How to run symfony database migration via ssh on plesk server?
I want to run migration of the deployed symfony application on plesk server. As you can see below, php is working and even my symfony application:
makwins.com_xpzik8d0rki@estudiofritz:~$ php -v
PHP 8.1.29 (cli) (built: Jun  6 2024 18:29:58) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.29, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.29, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

I ran composer install with plesk PHP Composer
The website was working, about the table doesn't contains the database because I can't run migration.
As you can see during login, I got that error :

When I am trying to run migration, I am getting this error.
makwins.com_xpzik8d0rki@estudiofritz:~$ php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migr     ate
Could not open input file: bin/console

Did anyone have any ideas about how to run a migration on plesk server, or should I create all table one by one?

Launch composer install/update first. Then check the permissions and the owner of the file and which user you are using when you log via SSH, it might differ from the owner of the file. Usually we use chmod +xr (0775 or read for all, write for all except for public, execute for all) on an executable file.

I have finally resolved the problem instead of bin/console in the migration command, it should be url_of_app/bin/console.
